# How to select default option in Material-UI Autocomplete component dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am looking for a way to pre-set a default option in a Autocomplete component, just when the ajax call completes loading the list of options. 
So the use case would be this: when the user opens the page, in the background a list of options would be loaded into state from the ajax response. I want to select the first retrieved option from the list, as soon as it gets loaded. Currently, I just have a basic way to offer a list of options:

```
  <Autocomplete
     options={defaultProps.options}
     getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
                 renderInput={params => (
                  <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" fullWidth />
     )}
  />
```

but don't know to select the first one when it gets loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using useEffect to demonstrate an ajax request on component mount.

You can use the `value` property to set the value after the component has been rendered.

While waiting for the ajax request to resolve, you can use the `loading` prop to change the component mode to `loading`

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
  const [def, setDef] = useState(null);

  useEffect((()=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      const tempArr = [{name:'Subject'},{name:'Another Subject'}];
      setOptions(tempArr);
      setDef(tempArr[0]);
    }, 1000);
  }), []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Autocomplete</h1>
      {<Autocomplete
        options={options}
        loading={!def}
        value={def}
        getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
          renderInput={params => (
              <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" fullWidth />
        )}
      />}
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

In latest version of Material UI theres an `autoHighlight` prop.

```js
<Autocomplete
    options={defaultProps.options}
    getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
        renderInput={params => (
        <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" fullWidth />
    )}
    autoHighlight // add this
/>
```

See the [API for Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/)